# Android: Listview select items

Tags: android

Using android studio and I have a large product list for a grocery store and want to be able to select items from that list. I then want the selected items to appear in another listview such as a users shopping cart.

#Updated
I have now created a checkable list view. How can I take the checked boxes and add them to another activity/listview that I have created.

```
enter code here import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
ArrayList<String> selectedItems=new ArrayList<>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView chl=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.checkable_list);
    chl.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    String[] items={"Bacon","Sports Drinks","Detergent","Towels","Frozen 
  Pizza","Water"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
 (this,R.layout.rowlayout,R.id.txt_title,items);
    chl.setAdapter(adapter);
    chl.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedItem=((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            if (selectedItem.contains(selectedItem)) {
                selectedItems.remove(selectedItem);
            }
                else
                    selectedItems.add(selectedItem);

            }
        });




}











public void showSelectedItems(View view){
    String items="";
    for (String item:selectedItems){
        items+="-"+item+"\n";
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added To Your Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}
```

Comment: I have created a custom list view now. I am still having trouble calling data from one list view and sending into another one. I was hoping to make it like a shopping cart where you would stay on the first list view even though you were clicking on items. I have a toast that states what items are being selected

Answer (score 0):

Please give me MORE information for your Question.

First of all

You have to make a custom listview that call **mOneListView** and set method `OnItemClickListener` to **mOneListView's ListViewAdapter**.
and make another mTwoListView be called by mOneListView's Item.

I think your problem is do not know how to make a custom listview and make a listener for Item of List.
[CHECK IT OUT.](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=make%20a%20custom%20listview%20android&*)

Comment: Right now I have a product list for a grocery store that contains various items. I want users to be able to click on these items. After the items are click I want them to be able to add them to their personal shopping cart while remaining on the large product list.

Comment: Would it be simpler with the new checkbox?